# How to edit a file, appending data at the beginning, without rewriting the whole file?

Tags: c#

I have a csv file, and I need to add a unique ID based on the first two characters of the file. I have the following code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f))
                    {
                        string currentLine;
                        int id = 0;

                        while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string row = currentLine.ToString();
                            string FirstTwoCharacters = currentLine.Substring(0, 2);


                            if (FirstTwoCharacters == "01")
                            {
                                id = id + 1;
                                row += "*" + id.ToString();

                                using (StreamWriter files = File.AppendText(dir + newfilename))
                                {
                                    files.WriteLine(row);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row += "*" + id.ToString();

                                using (StreamWriter files = File.AppendText(dir + newfilename))
                                {
                                    files.WriteLine(row);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

The csv files can be huge, 1Gb in size, around 6 million rows. Just wanted advice, if there is a quicker way to handling this, as it currently can take 3+ hours to process a file, and multiple files can be received in one go.

Comment: chunk the data instead of writing to the file for each line.  That's so much overhead.

Comment: string row = currentLine.ToString();... string ToString?

Comment: string to string, making absolute sure, or just some bad code...you decide.

Comment: That would be bad code. From the docs: "Because this method simply returns the current string unchanged, there is no need to call it directly"

Comment: ...it was a joke. It was my error in the code as I had amended it somewhat and left that hanging around. It is indeed bad code.

Comment: You just can't. But 1GB is really like nothing at all and, as you have seen the time was wasted somewhere else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opening the (`File.AppendText`) inside the `while` loop is costly, move this  to outside   the `while`

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f))
{
                string currentLine;
                int id = 0;
                using (StreamWriter files = File.AppendText(dir + newfilename))
                {
                    while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string row = currentLine.ToString();
                        string FirstTwoCharacters = currentLine.Substring(0, 2);


                        if (FirstTwoCharacters == "01")
                        {
                            id = id + 1;
                            row += "*" + id.ToString();

                            files.WriteLine(row);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row += "*" + id.ToString();

                            files.WriteLine(row);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This has sorted me right out, thats one to remember. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening new file for appending line for each line of input file you can keep stream writer opened:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f))
using (StreamWriter files = File.AppendText(dir + newfilename))
{
    string currentLine;
    int id = 0;

    while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string firstTwoCharacters = currentLine.Substring(0, 2);

        if (firstTwoCharacters == "01")
             id++;

        files.WriteLine(currentLine + "*" + id);
    }
}
```

You can also use `File.ReadLines` to enumerate source lines:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(dir + newfilename))
{
    int id = 0;

    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(f))
    {
        if (line.Substring(0,2) == "01")
           id++;

        writer.WriteLine($"{line}*{id}");
    }
}
```

Or even LINQ approach

```
int id = 0;
var newLines = from line in File.ReadLines(f)
               let incrementId = line.Substring(0,2) == "01"
               select $"{line}*{incrementId ? (++id) : id}";

File.WriteAllLines(dir + newfilename, newLines);
```